# ssh in home network by hostname (dynamic IP)

Tags: ssh, networking

I have a home network with dynamic ip addresses. I would like to obtain ssh-connect from one linux desktop to another one (actually, Ubuntu to CentOS). I can connect with ip address:

```
loom@ubuntu-desktop:~ $ ssh 192.168.0.110
```

The problem is dynamic ip. Next day I must know the new ip to connect. I unsuccessfully tried to use hostname rather than ip:

```
loom@ubuntu-desktop:~ $ ssh centos-desktop
ssh: Could not resolve hostname centos-desktop: Name or service not known

loom@ubuntu-desktop:~ $ ssh centos-desktop.area
ssh: Could not resolve hostname centos-desktop.area: Name or service not known
```

There are `hosts` files for both computers.
Centos

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.0.1   centos-desktop.area centos-desktop
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

and Ubuntu

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu-desktop.area ubuntu-desktop

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

How can I organize ssh access in my network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.uguu.waw.pl/2015/05/21/mdns-netbsd-linux-osx/

> Multicast DNS uses a special domain called "local". Host names are automatically registered in this domain.

You should find it already works if you try `ssh ubuntu-desktop.local` on the ubuntu system, but obviously that's not going to be very useful...

> The responder is implemented by Avahi service, which is already a part
>   of all recent distributions.
>
> The resolver is implemented as additional
>   nsswitch module mdns, which unfortunately is not included in
>   RHEL/CentOS.
>
> However, mdns module can be
>   installed from EPEL repository (so be sure to enable it first).
>
> Next, install the necessary packages:
>
> # yum -y install avahi nss-mdns
>
> # systemctl start <del>avahi-service</del> avahi-daemon
>
> # systemctl enable <del>avahi-service</del> avahi-daemon
>
> Next, enable the mdns module in /etc/nsswitch.conf by modifying the
>   hosts: line:
>
> hosts: files mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns
>
> If you're using IPv4 only, then use mdns4_minimal and mdns4 instead.

Comment: Thank you. However, I've got an error, when tried to start `avahi-service`:  `Failed to start avahi-service.service: Unit avahi-service.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
`

Comment: Huh. Actually I've never seen it spelled avahi-service before, only `avahi-daemon`.

Comment: @Loom ^ does this answer your original question now?